# Idiomatic and efficient way to add two ranges element-wise

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl

Is there any efficient and idiomatic way to perform the following operation?

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::vector<int> b = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; ++i)
{
    a[i] += b[i];
}
```

I am trying to avoid the brackets/index notation and only use iterators in order for the operation to work with any container with forward iterators. I thought of the following solution:

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::vector<int> b = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(),
               b.begin(),
               a.begin(),
               std::plus<int>());
```

However, there is the redundancy of `a.begin()` and I only get to use `+` and not `+=`. Is there some algorithm in the standard library that would allow me to use iterators without having any redundancy or do I have to write the full loops by hand?

Comment: If `transform` does not work for you, you can always define a `+=` operator that lets you write `a += b` for a clean and easy to understand look.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Isn't there any in the standard library?

Comment: I couldn't find one for vectors...

Comment: Unfortunately there is still no binary `for_each` in the standard yet.

Comment: `auto transform_inplace = [](auto first1, auto last1, auto first2, auto&& op){return std::transform(first, last1, first2, first1, std::forward<decltype(op)>(op));};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the kind of generic function I was looking for and finally went with the following function that I named `range_map` ("map the given function element-wise with two given ranges"). As the comments point, it is actually no more than a binary `std::for_each`:

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class BinaryOperation>
void range_map(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
               InputIt2 first2, BinaryOperation binary_op)
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        binary_op(*first1++, *first2++);
    }
}
```

I created the class `plus_assign` the following way:

```
template<typename T>
struct plus_assign
{
    void operator()(T &lhs, const T &rhs) const 
    {
        lhs += rhs;
    }
};
```

And then my code becomes:

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::vector<int> b = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

range_map(a.begin(), a.end(),
          b.begin(),
          plus_assign<int>());
```

---

There is also the unary counterpart of the function `range_map`, to map a given functor to a range:

```
template<class InputIt, class BinaryOperation>
void range_map(InputIt first, InputIt last,
               UnaryOperation unary_op)
{
    while (first != last) {
        unary_op(*first1++);
    }
}
```

Comment: In light of all the other answers, this is really a self-answer that was desperately needed and more than deserves an upvote. But note, that your unary `range_map` (whose argument should be called `unary_op` by the way) is nothing else than a `std::for_each`.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps something that was intended to become idiomatic, but never quite did:

```
std::valarray<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
std::valarray<int> b = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
```

Now you can do these

```
std::valarray<int> c = a + b; //apply '+' element-wise; store result in c

a += b;  //apply '+=' element-wise
```

See the [documentation of std::valarray](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) for more details.

Comment: It is `std::valarray`, no? And `a+=b` is even better, because this is what the OP wants.

Comment: Well, I already thought about `std::valarray`. Unfortunately, this solution only works with it and not with any forward traversable container :)

Comment: @TemplateRex: oops -- I'd forgotten (a serious problem at my age...)

Comment: Its not always possible to use a `valarray` for `vector<int>`. `valarry` is a special data structure for specific usecases. The question is what to to do best with a `vector<int>`

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with the redundancy of `a.begin()`?

If you're not happy with it, just invent your own algorithm: `transform_inplace`

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class BinaryOperator>
OutputIterator transform_inplace (InputIterator first,
                                  InputIterator last,
                                  OutputIterator result,
                                  BinaryOperator op)
{
  while (first != last) {
    *result = op(*result, *first);
    ++result; 
    ++first;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `UnaryOperator` should be named as `BinaryOperator` (or better `BinaryFunctor`). `OutputIterator` is `InputIterator2` in fact.

Comment: Unfortunately it still uses `+` and `=` instead of `+=`, which might not be problem for fundamentals, but could be for other stuff.

Answer (score 4):

If you were to use this more than once, and you were interested in a simple interface in the spirit of the Standard Library, you could create a simple template class for the specific use case (which I refer to as "Range Increment"), and write something like:

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

template<typename InputIt>
InputIt range_increment(InputIt dbeg, InputIt dend, InputIt sbeg) {
  while(dbeg!=dend) {
    *(dbeg++) += (*sbeg++);
  }
  return dbeg;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  std::vector<int> b = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

  range_increment(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());

  for(auto x:a) {
    std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

Which yields:

```
6
8
10
12
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I'd call it "idiomatic", but:

```
assert(a.size()==b.size());
auto bi = b.begin();
for (auto& i : a) {
  i += *(bi++);
}
```

is pretty concise.

Answer (score 0):

Use operator overload

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int>& operator += (std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int> const& b)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i != a.size(); ++i)
        a[i] += b[i];

    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   std::vector<int> a { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
   std::vector<int> b { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

   a += b;

   return 0;
}
```